# No method error for class variable defined with attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to define methods dynamically using an array of strings.

Here is a simple piece of code that should achieve that.

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :my_array

  def initialize(user, record)
    @my_array=[]
  end

  my_array.each do |element|
    alias_method "#{element}?".to_sym, :awesome_method
  end

  def awesome_method
    puts 'awesome'
  end

end
```

When I instantiate this class in the console, I get the following error

**NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)**

What is wrong with this code and how to make it work. any help highly appreciated :)

Edit 1: 
What I ultimately want to achieve is to inherit from SomeClass and override my_array in the child class to dynamically define methods with its attributes like so

```
class OtherClass < SomeClass

  my_array = %w[method1 method2 method3] 
  # Some mechanism to over write my_array. 

end
```

And then use `self.inherited` to dynamically define methods in child class.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: You call `my_array` from the class scope, while it’s defined on the instance scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you use an instance variable (@my_array) and an attr_accessor over it, and then try to access my_array from class level (that is, from the body of the class definition, outside of any methods). But instance variables only exist at instance level, so it is not available in the class scope.

One solution (the natural one, and the one which you would probably use in other languages) is to use a class variable: @@my_array. But class variables in ruby are a little problematic, so the best solution would be to make use of class instance variables, like that:

```
class SomeClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_array
  end

  @my_array=[]

  def initialize(user, record)
  end

  @my_array.each do |element|
    alias_method "#{element}?".to_sym, :awesome_method
  end

  def awesome_method
    puts 'awesome'
  end

end
```

The syntax is a little tricky, so, if you look that up and it still doesn't makes sense, try just reading about scopes and using a regular class variable with @@.

Edit:

Ok, so, after your edit, it became more clear what you are trying to accomplish. A full working example is like follows:

```
class SomeClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_array
  end

  @my_array=[]

  def awesome_method
    puts 'awesome'
  end

  def self.build!
    @my_array.each do |element|
      self.define_method("#{element}?".to_sym){ awesome_method }
    end
  end

end

class ChildClass < SomeClass
  @my_array = %w[test little_test]

  self.build!
end

child_instance = ChildClass.new

child_instance.test?
>> awesome

child_instance.little_test?
>> awesome
```

So, I've made some tweaks on SomeClass:

1. It does not need an initialize method
2. I tried to use the inherited hook for this problem. It won't ever work, because this hook is called as soon as "ChildClass < SomeClass" is written, and this must be before you can define something like @my_array = %w[test little_test]. So, I have added a self.build! method that must be called in the child instances so that they build their methods from my_array. This is inevitable, but I think it is also good, because it makes more explicit in the subclasses that you are doing something interesting there.
3. I think you want "define_method", not "alias_method".
4. awesome_method in passed in a block, which is ruby's way of doing functional programming.

With that done, ChildClass inherits from SomeClass, and it's instances have the dynamically created methods 'test?' and 'little_test?'.

Comment: Please see Edit 1 of the description. Any suggestions? 
Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: Works beautifully!
I have two doubts though for the build! method. 1. Should we do with my_array instead of @my_array since accessor is defined in singleton class? 2. should we use `define_method` instead of `self.define_method` ?

If these suggestions are correct please update your answer. I am marking it correct anyway. 
Thanks a lot for help !!

Comment: I think define_method works by invoking the method definition on the current context, which is self, so there is no difference between define_method and self.define_method. I'm not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: As to \@my_array vs my_array, when you call "my_array" you are just accessing \@my_array through the accessor you defined, so there is no difference. I've included the accessor because I supposed you wanted to call my_array from outside the class definition (you could change my_array and call ChildClass.build! from the outside). But, if you don't need this feature, you can left out the accessor code altogether. In this case, you will need to call \@my_array or you get a NameError exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `my_array` to class level accessible, in my case class constant.

```
class SomeClass
  DYNAMIC_METHOD_NAMES = %w(method_a method_b method_C).freeze

  def initialize(user, record)
  end

  DYNAMIC_METHOD_NAMES.each do |element|
    alias_method "#{element}?".to_sym, :awesome_method
  end

  def awesome_method
    puts 'awesome'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right this will work. But I need to overwrite the DYNAMIC_METHOD_NAMES when I inherit from this class and use self.inherited to dynamically define methods in child class. Any suggestion on how best to achieve that. 
Please see edit 1 in the question description.